# how to have nested multiprocessing manager dictionaries in a class

Tags: python-3.x, multiprocessing, pickle

I have created a simple class to store multiprocessing values. The **init** function looks like this:

```
def __init__(self):
        Manager = multiprocessing.Manager()
        self.FMT = '%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S:%f'
        self.lock = multiprocessing.Lock()
        self.grabDays = Manager.dict()
        self.changeAmt = 0
        self.command = multiprocessing.Value(ctypes.c_wchar_p, 'start sequence')
        self.get_best = multiprocessing.Value(ctypes.c_bool, False)
        self.done = multiprocessing.Value(ctypes.c_bool, False)
        self.status = multiprocessing.Value(ctypes.c_wchar_p, 'nothing')
        self.discrepencies = Manager.dict()
        self.making = Manager.dict()
```

This works fine, however if I made `Manager` as `self.Manager` but both still equal to `multiprocessing.Manager()`. I would get an error from trying to pass the class to other functions that the class is not pickle-able. If I were to make Manager a class variable I would also get an error. This works fine for simple manipulations of one dictionary, but there are functions in my class that use nested dictionaries.

For example:

```
Manager = multiprocessing.Manager()
num = 1
keys = list(self.grabDays.keys())
if num not in keys:
      self.grabDays[num] = Manager.dict()
```

This does not return an error, however, the other processes cannot see that it is nested and everything that has been done to it. Is there a way to have nested manager dictionaries?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thought this solution up, which in all honesty is not very elegant, but, it works. This nested dictionary example will be 3 sub-dictionaries deep, and involve a time variable. This way there isn't much that would be hard to figure out.

The first step is to not initialize the dictionary you want to create as a manager dictionary in the class you created, but as a manager list. This looks like this:

```
def __init__(self):
      self.manager = multiprocessing.Manager()
      self.grabDays = self.manager.list()
```

Obviously you can name yours whatever. Next, I created a function to initialize this list into specific strings that will tell my program what the variables are. Also, note that I said a 3 layer dictionary but the string will not have the third layer in it. This is because the third layer will be a counter in the dictionary that is initialized by the dictionary creator function. The reason for the ** in the string is because I know that there would never be 2 asterisks in a row in any of the variables I am going to insert. You can obviously choose any separator you would like, but it is important you have one, otherwise this will not work.

This is my function to add values:

```
def addGrabDaysClass(self,time, price, slope, volume, percentage, day, hour):
        self.day = day
        self.hour = hour
        try:    time = time.strftime('%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S:%f')
        except: pass
        self.grabDays.append(str(day)+'**'+str(hour)+'**'+str(slope)+'**'+str(price)+'**'+str(volume)+'**'+str(percentage)+'**'+str(time))
```

I also wanted for there to be a max of 15 days of data to collect, I have created a working function to do that as well, posted below:

```
import calendar
def updateGrabbedDaysDict(self):
        #self.keys = self.grabDays.keys()
        #del self.grabDays[self.keys[-1]]
        storeToRemove = []
        lister =  list(self.get(name='grabDays', model='Array'))
        list2 = lister[-1].split('**')
        day = float(list2[0])
        time = datetime.strptime(list2[6], '%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S:%f')
        lastYear = time.year
        lastMonth = time.month -1
        if lastMonth < 0:
            lastMonth = 12
            lastYear - 1
        daysPreviousMonth = calendar.monthrange(lastYear,lastMonth)[1]
        dayLookFor = day-15
        if dayLookFor < 0:
            dayLookFor = daysPreviousMonth + dayLookFor
        for i in range(len(lister)):
            list2 = lister[i].split('**')
            day = float(list2[0])
            if dayLookFor == day:
                storeToRemove.append(list2[i])
        for i in range(len(storeToRemove)):
            while storeToRemove[i] in self.grabDays:
                self.grabDays.remove(storeToRemove[i])
```

This is the function that I created that can be called to add information to the manager list, and make sure it is updated:

```
from datetime import datetime
def addGrabDays(time, price, slope, volume, percentage, arg = None):
    arg.addGrabDaysClass(time, price, slope, volume, percentage, time.day, time.hour)
    arg.updateGrabbedDaysDict()
```

lastly, this is how you would return it into a working dictionary:

```
def returnData(name, arg=None):
    if name == 'grabDays':  
        lister =  list(arg.get(name='grabDays', model='Array'))
        dictionary = {}
        #self.grabDays.append(str(day)+'**'+str(hour)+'**'+str(slope)+'**'+str(price)+'**'+str(volume)+'**'+str(percentage)+'**'+str(time))
        for i in range(len(lister)):
            list2 = lister[i].split('**')
            day = float(list2[0])
            hour = float(list2[1])
            slope = float(list2[2])
            price = float(list2[3])
            volume = float(list2[4])
            percentage = float(list2[5])
            time = datetime.strptime(list2[6], '%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S:%f')
            keys = list(dictionary.keys())
            if day not in keys:
                dictionary[day] = {}
            keys = list(dictionary[day].keys())
            if hour not in keys:
                dictionary[day][hour] = {}
            keys = list(dictionary[day][hour].keys())
            if not keys:
                counter = 0
            else:
                counter = keys[-1]+1

            dictionary[day][hour][counter] = {'slope':slope, 'price':price, 'volume':volume, 'time':time, 'percentage':percentage}
        return dictionary
```

Note that the comments I had copied from the part where I inputed the string so that I wouldn't have to scroll up and down every time. After putting that code in a python file I called storeData, I was able to create a tester example. If you are still reading and are interested in a basic, but to show that the code works, example here is one:

code:

```
from storeData import *
import multiprocessing
import time
from datetime import datetime
def try2(arg):
    now = datetime.now()
    for i in range(0,35):
        addGrabDays(time=now, price=(i*9), slope=(i*5), volume=(i*3), percentage=(i*8), arg = arg)
    time.sleep(1)
    print('going to print in next process')
    time.sleep(2)
    print('done!')
def nextTry(arg):
    time.sleep(2)
    print(returnData('grabDays', arg=arg))
def foregrounder():
    ult = data()
    p1 = Process(target = try2, args=(ult,))
    p1.start()
    p2 = Process(target = nextTry, args=(ult,))
    p2.start()
    p1.join()
    p2.join()
if __name__ == "__main__":
    foregrounder()
```

result of the code:

```
going to print in next process
{14.0: {16.0: {0: {'slope': 0.0, 'price': 0.0, 'volume': 0.0, 'time': datetime.datetime(2020, 8, 14, 16, 8, 14, 383679), 'percentage': 0.0}, 1: {'slope': 5.0, 'price': 9.0, 'volume': 3.0, 'time': datetime.datetime(2020, 8, 14, 16, 8, 14, 383679), 'percentage': 8.0}, 2: {'slope': 10.0, 'price': 18.0, 'volume': 6.0, 'time': datetime.datetime(2020, 8, 14, 16, 8, 14, 383679), 'percentage': 16.0}, 3: {'slope': 15.0, 'price': 27.0, 'volume': 9.0, 'time': datetime.datetime(2020, 8, 14, 16, 8, 14, 383679), 'percentage': 24.0}, 4: {'slope': 20.0, 'price': 36.0, 'volume': 12.0, 'time': datetime.datetime(2020, 8, 14, 16, 8, 14, 383679), 'percentage': 32.0}, 5: {'slope': 25.0, 'price': 45.0, 'volume': 15.0, 'time': datetime.datetime(2020, 8, 14, 16, 8, 14, 383679), 'percentage': 40.0}, 6: {'slope': 30.0, 'price': 54.0, 'volume': 18.0, 'time': datetime.datetime(2020, 8, 14, 16, 8, 14, 383679), 'percentage': 48.0}, 7: {'slope': 35.0, 'price': 63.0, 'volume': 21.0, 'time': datetime.datetime(2020, 8, 14, 16, 8, 14, 383679), 'percentage': 56.0}, 8: {'slope': 40.0, 'price': 72.0, 'volume': 24.0, 'time': datetime.datetime(2020, 8, 14, 16, 8, 14, 383679), 'percentage': 64.0}, 9: {'slope': 45.0, 'price': 81.0, 'volume': 27.0, 'time': datetime.datetime(2020, 8, 14, 16, 8, 14, 383679), 'percentage': 72.0}, 10: {'slope': 50.0, 'price': 90.0, 'volume': 30.0, 'time': datetime.datetime(2020, 8, 14, 16, 8, 14, 383679), 'percentage': 80.0}, 11: {'slope': 55.0, 'price': 99.0, 'volume': 33.0, 'time': datetime.datetime(2020, 8, 14, 16, 8, 14, 383679), 'percentage': 88.0}, 12: {'slope': 60.0, 'price': 108.0, 'volume': 36.0, 'time': datetime.datetime(2020, 8, 14, 16, 8, 14, 383679), 'percentage': 96.0}, 13: {'slope': 65.0, 'price': 117.0, 'volume': 39.0, 'time': datetime.datetime(2020, 8, 14, 16, 8, 14, 383679), 'percentage': 104.0}, 14: {'slope': 70.0, 'price': 126.0, 'volume': 42.0, 'time': datetime.datetime(2020, 8, 14, 16, 8, 14, 383679), 'percentage': 112.0}, 15: {'slope': 75.0, 'price': 135.0, 'volume': 45.0, 'time': datetime.datetime(2020, 8, 14, 16, 8, 14, 383679), 'percentage': 120.0}, 16: {'slope': 80.0, 'price': 144.0, 'volume': 48.0, 'time': datetime.datetime(2020, 8, 14, 16, 8, 14, 383679), 'percentage': 128.0}, 17: {'slope': 85.0, 'price': 153.0, 'volume': 51.0, 'time': datetime.datetime(2020, 8, 14, 16, 8, 14, 383679), 'percentage': 136.0}, 18: {'slope': 90.0, 'price': 162.0, 'volume': 54.0, 'time': datetime.datetime(2020, 8, 14, 16, 8, 14, 383679), 'percentage': 144.0}, 19: {'slope': 95.0, 'price': 171.0, 'volume': 57.0, 'time': datetime.datetime(2020, 8, 14, 16, 8, 14, 383679), 'percentage': 152.0}, 20: {'slope': 100.0, 'price': 180.0, 'volume': 60.0, 'time': datetime.datetime(2020, 8, 14, 16, 8, 14, 383679), 'percentage': 160.0}, 21: {'slope': 105.0, 'price': 189.0, 'volume': 63.0, 'time': datetime.datetime(2020, 8, 14, 16, 8, 14, 383679), 'percentage': 168.0}, 22: {'slope': 110.0, 'price': 198.0, 'volume': 66.0, 'time': datetime.datetime(2020, 8, 14, 16, 8, 14, 383679), 'percentage': 176.0}, 23: {'slope': 115.0, 'price': 207.0, 'volume': 69.0, 'time': datetime.datetime(2020, 8, 14, 16, 8, 14, 383679), 'percentage': 184.0}, 24: {'slope': 120.0, 'price': 216.0, 'volume': 72.0, 'time': datetime.datetime(2020, 8, 14, 16, 8, 14, 383679), 'percentage': 192.0}, 25: {'slope': 125.0, 'price': 225.0, 'volume': 75.0, 'time': datetime.datetime(2020, 8, 14, 16, 8, 14, 383679), 'percentage': 200.0}, 26: {'slope': 130.0, 'price': 234.0, 'volume': 78.0, 'time': datetime.datetime(2020, 8, 14, 16, 8, 14, 383679), 'percentage': 208.0}, 27: {'slope': 135.0, 'price': 243.0, 'volume': 81.0, 'time': datetime.datetime(2020, 8, 14, 16, 8, 14, 383679), 'percentage': 216.0}, 28: {'slope': 140.0, 'price': 252.0, 'volume': 84.0, 'time': datetime.datetime(2020, 8, 14, 16, 8, 14, 383679), 'percentage': 224.0}, 29: {'slope': 145.0, 'price': 261.0, 'volume': 87.0, 'time': datetime.datetime(2020, 8, 14, 16, 8, 14, 383679), 'percentage': 232.0}, 30: {'slope': 150.0, 'price': 270.0, 'volume': 90.0, 'time': datetime.datetime(2020, 8, 14, 16, 8, 14, 383679), 'percentage': 240.0}, 31: {'slope': 155.0, 'price': 279.0, 'volume': 93.0, 'time': datetime.datetime(2020, 8, 14, 16, 8, 14, 383679), 'percentage': 248.0}, 32: {'slope': 160.0, 'price': 288.0, 'volume': 96.0, 'time': datetime.datetime(2020, 8, 14, 16, 8, 14, 383679), 'percentage': 256.0}, 33: {'slope': 165.0, 'price': 297.0, 'volume': 99.0, 'time': datetime.datetime(2020, 8, 14, 16, 8, 14, 383679), 'percentage': 264.0}, 34: {'slope': 170.0, 'price': 306.0, 'volume': 102.0, 'time': datetime.datetime(2020, 8, 14, 16, 8, 14, 383679), 'percentage': 272.0}}}}
done!
```

if you look closely you can see that there were 35 instances made (include the zero) and it has 3 layers. Although, because they were all at the same made time, you will have to trust me that the multiple layers at different hours and days will still work just like the counter did as demonstrated above.